# Rails DataTable: How to set iDisplayLength based on ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, coffeescript

I have a ruby variable that contains the number of rows a user would like displayed in a table.

I am using dataTable gem to format the table in the view and would like the iDisplayLength set to the value contained in @user.table_size variable

my coffee script has

```
jQuery ->
  $('.table').dataTable({
  "sDom": "R<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "iDisplayLength": ####PAGE_SIZE_HERE####,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
  "bStateSave": true
});
```

How do I get it to pick up my page size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file to .js.coffee.erb then you can use variables from your Rails environment as usual using

```
<%= @user.table_size %>
```